# How to encapsulate multiple $in queries in mongodb php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, sorting

Here `PRODUCT_NAME` and `BRAND_NAME` are two different columns from same document. And I want to apply a filter on the selected product and brand names.

My array is something like this

```
Array
(
    [PRODUCT_NAME] => Array
        (
            [$and] => Array
                (
                    [$in] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Product1
                            [1] => Product2
                        )

                )

        )

    [BRAND_NAME] => Array
        (
            [$and] => Array
                (
                    [$in] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Brand1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this with mongodb ( assuming last version ) is to use mongodb aggregation and in particular [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

So as example in your case:

```
db.yourcollection.aggregate( [
  { $unwind : "$firstattribute" } , // 1
  { $unwind : "$PRODUCT_NAME" },    // 2
  { $unwind : "$BRAND_NAME" },      // 3
] )
```

Now some explanation:

1. because in your example, you provided an array, you have to unwind it, if is not so, please remove
2. here you unwind product name array
3. and here brand name

Note: I can provide a better (and runnable) solution with a real example ( a json with at least 2 elements in each array

Comment: you are welcome, if you can provide a better json solution could be more precise, otherwise please accept this answer if solve your problem